# what is the difference between networkx2 adjlist_inner_dict_factory and adjlist_outter_dict_factory

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-list

In networkx 1, graph has a method called `adjlist_dict_factory`, which can be used to create adjacency list. In networkx 2, there are two methods

- `adjlist_inner_dict_factory`
- `adjlist_outer_dict_factory`

What does inner and outer refer to here?

Specifically, for the [subgraph extraction code in 1.10](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html#Graph.subgraph), which one should I used to replace `adjlist_dict_factory`?

I tried both of them, and it seems they both work...

In IPython notebook, the information from `??` also look the same for them.

```
In [4]: g.adjlist_outer_dict_factory??
Init signature: g.adjlist_outer_dict_factory(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
dict() -> new empty dictionary
dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
    (key, value) pairs
dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
    d = {}
    for k, v in iterable:
        d[k] = v
dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
    in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
Type:           type

In [5]: nx.__version__
Out[5]: '2.2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html):

> Subclasses (Advanced):
>
> The Graph class uses a dict-of-dict-of-dict data structure. The outer dict (node_dict) holds adjacency information keyed by node. The next dict (adjlist_dict) represents the adjacency information and holds edge data keyed by neighbor. The inner dict (edge_attr_dict) represents the edge data and holds edge attribute values keyed by attribute names.
>
> Each of these three dicts can be replaced in a subclass by a user defined dict-like object. In general, the dict-like features should be maintained but extra features can be added. To replace one of the dicts create a new graph class by changing the class(!) variable holding the factory for that dict-like structure. The variable names are node_dict_factory, node_attr_dict_factory, adjlist_inner_dict_factory, adjlist_outer_dict_factory, edge_attr_dict_factory and graph_attr_dict_factory.

So these functions are used in subclasses of networkx2 graphs for:

- `adjlist_outer_dict_factory`: nodes adjacency (are edges exist)
- `adjlist_inner_dict_factory`: edges data